# During Phone call using custom UIview

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, phone-call

I can start a phone call using this code

```
var url = NSUrl.FromString("tel:+xxxxx"); 
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
```

it opens iphones phone call ui. can i use a custome ui during this call. for example i want to show an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't - this is because control is passed to the Phone.app (which is a native app written by Apple).